# Вывести отдельно подпункты активного элемента меню

Tags: php, wordpress

Нужно вывести на странице все дочерние элементы активного элемента меню.
Т.е например у меня есть `<ul class='primary'><li>О нас <ul><li>О компании</li><li>Филиалы</li></ul> </li></ul`

Т.е если я перешел на страницу О нас , то нужно продублировать все подпункты элемента  О нас в отдельном месте на странице.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В function.php  прописать следующий код:

```
function menu_childs_only( $items, $args ) {
global $stitle; // заглобалим переменную, в неё потом сунем имя самого верхнего элемента, для заголовка меню
if ( empty($args->childs_only) ) // если параметр не был передан
    return $items; // обычный вывод меню
$newitems = array(); // подготовим пустые массивы
$ids = array(); // здесь будут id всех активных пунктов
foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) { // пробегаем по каждому элементу, этот
    if ( $item->current ) { // если элемент активный
        if ($item->menu_item_parent != 0) { // и если есть родительский элемент
            $ids[] = $item->menu_item_parent; // пишем его в массив
        }
    }
}
foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) { // пробежим еще раз
    if (($item->current_item_ancestor || $item->current || in_array('current-post-ancestor', $item->classes))) { // если элемент активный и самый верхний
        $stitle = $item->title; // запишем заголовок меню
        static $stitle; // пишем один раз
        $ids[] = $item->ID; // добавляем его id в массив
    }
    if (in_array($item->menu_item_parent, $ids)) { // если id есть среди активных id
        $newitems[] = $item; // пишем весь элемент в массив новых элементов
        if ($item->current) { // вот это я не помню для чего, но нужно
            $ids[] = $item->ID;
        }
    }
}
return $newitems; // возвращаем отфильтрованные элементы меню
```

}

Вызвать в том месте на странице, где необходимо.